# Simple linear regression for predictive purposes

Tags: probability-theory

Relationship between X and Y, the first and second year batting averages of a random baseball player is expressed as simple linear regression Y=0.159 + 0.4X + e with e ~ N(0,variance)

If a player's batting average is 0.200 in his first year, what would you predict for the seond year?

I'm wondering if I just can replace X=0.200 into the equation above to give the result Y or I have to find prediction interval for Y, although I don't have enough data to find prediction interval

Answer (score 1):

You know that $Y$ has the expression
$$
Y = 0.159 + 0.4\times 0.2 + e
$$with $e$ a random variable with expectation 0. Hence the best prediction is
$$\hat Y = 0.159 + 0.4\times 0.2
$$

which is the expected value of the second year batting average, given that the first year average is $0.200$.

Here is the shape of the distribution of the second year average. Here
$m =  0.159 + 0.4\times 0.2$. You see that as the distribution is symetric around $m$, $m$ is the widest choice.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very clear. Thank you for helping me